# How can I introduce bounds checking for std::string in a unit test?

Tags: c++, string, unit-testing

I have a module that uses `std::string` as part of its interface. I would like to run a unit test on this module using bounds checking on index access of the `std::string`. That is, if a string `s` has only 5 characters, I would like to throw an exception of some kind when accessing `s[5]` (or `s[-1]`).

Here is the basics of my code. The module is all implemented in a single header file.

### module.h

```
#include <string>

int decode(const std::string &data) { ... }
```

### test.cpp

```
#include "module.h"

#include "gtest/gtest.h" // using Google Test

TEST(Module, Decode) {
    ASSERT_EQ(decode("...") == 5); // or whatever
}
```

I suppose one way would be to implement the `module.h` in terms of templates, where the implementation depends on some type that allows indexing. However, there's no reason for the implementation in `module.h` to use anything other than `std::string` in the real world; such a feature would only be used for unit testing. I'd rather not use templates here.

I'm okay with using preprocessor tricks as long as the tricks are limited to the `test.cpp` module. For example, I don't want to have to `#define ModuleString std::string` before including `module.h` under normal circumstances.

What are my options here?

Comment: Instead of the `operator[]`, you could use `std::string::at`, which already does boundary checking and throws `std::out_of_range`. Feasible?

Comment: Now that's a good idea. I wonder why I didn't know that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the `operator[]`, you could use [`std::string::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at), which already does boundary checking and throws `std::out_of_range`. Feasible?

Comment: That does indeed solve my problem. However, I wonder if there is still a more general technique for adding such additional capability for unit test.

Comment: Such technique would be hard (if not impossible) to introduce in a built-in type. Additionally, the compiler static analysis cannot help because `std::string` uses heap memory (think of `-fbounds-check` in gcc). An option would be to extend the type in question, overriding the methods that need boundary checking. But that would require you to replace the usage of `std::string` with your extended type, which kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of extending `std::string` with `std::BoundsCheckingString` with all the appropriate constructors and bounds checking implementations, and then `#define string BoundsCheckingString` at just the right moment, but didn't quite get the details worked out.

Comment: @Greg: putting more thoughts on it, I'd suggest creating a completely new type that acts like a proxy, having a `std::string` member. You wrap the string, and forward the calls after you perform your boundary checks. One way or the other, figuring out the right methods is not the easiest task.

Comment: Right, that would ensure that you add bounds checking for all calls that might require it (and not rely on inherited implementations of anything). It still would need the same preprocessor dance.

Comment: Yeah, the type redefinition is unavoidable AFAIK.